# What is in a backup.ab file?

Tags: adb, backup, restore

Using ADB tools for Android (my device had root), I executed the following command:

```
adb backup -all
```

After confirming the backup operation, I got a file titled backup.ab that is 350MB. A month later, my device booted with a System UI crash, and would not let me access anything on it. I got a new one (same model), and it is unrooted. What would running the command

```
adb restore backup.ab
```

restore to my Android? I want to know what is in the backup (and what restoring it would do), because I want to keep my current userdata. The new device also has a more stable system, so I would not want to restore that, either.

NOTE: This question was marked as duplicate and then ignored, so it has been deleted and reposted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.ab** backups only apps data and their apks as well as system settings.

What **is** contained:

- apks and their data
- user vocabulary
- wallpaper
- launcher settings

What is **not** contained:

- contacts
- sms
- ringtones and custom sounds
- activated input layouts

More detailed [is here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315/94888).

Comment: Tak he note that SMSs are not backed up might be outdated, or at least vendor-specific. In my experience, they are backed up.